# Plotting, book recommendation

Tags: reference-request, graphing-functions, book-recommendation

My friend hinted that for her birthday she would like to get a book that explains how to make good, publishing-quality plots. I am not talking about tutorials about how to plot in Python or Matlab, etc. She would like a book that teaches how to present visual data (beautifully). She is a scientist doing a mathematics-physics related work. Does anyone know a reference? I couldn't find anything valid to scientists online...

Comment: Anything by Edward Tufte?

Comment: THE VISUAL DISPLAY OF QUANTITATIVE INFORMATION?

Comment: Say.  I think that was his first book.

Comment: I second (third?) the Edward Tufte suggestion. Another book worth considering is Hadley Wickham's book on `ggplot`, which is a modern implementation of the famous book "The Grammar of Graphics" by Leland Wilkinson.

Comment: there is an inexpensive book in number theory where the author applied Tufte's ideas, https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted an answer, you've been very helpful